inventory of designer workflow in sharepoint online and status
Can this script be streamlined?
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://colage.sharepoint.com" -Interactive
$sites = Get-PnPTenantSite
$workflowReport = @()
 
foreach ($site in $sites) {
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site.Url -Interactive
    $webs = Get-PnPSubWeb -Recurse
 
    foreach ($web in $webs) {
        $lists = Get-PnPList
 
        foreach ($list in $lists) {
            $workflows = Get-PnPWorkflowInstance -List $list
 
            foreach ($workflow in $workflows) {
                if ($workflow.Status -eq "Disabled") {
                    $workflowReport += [PSCustomObject]@{
                        SiteUrl = $site.Url
                        WebUrl = $web.Url
                        ListTitle = $list.Title
                        WorkflowName = $workflow.Name
                        Status = $workflow.Status
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 
$workflowReport | Export-Csv -Path "DisabledWorkflowsReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation

